# How to set ComboBoxEntry by default?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk2

I have a ComboBoxEntry:

```
my $com_entry = Gtk2::ComboBoxEntry->new($model, 0);
```

and I need to delete the user entry from a ComboBoxEntry (to set an empty value). The method `$com_entry->set_active_iter(undef);` of ComboBox doesn't work. 
Any ideas? Thanks for a response.

Comment: Maybe `$com_entry->set_active_iter("");` ?

Comment: Oh, no) this method gets only an iter type value or undef.

Answer (score 1):

According to what is meant by *"delete the user entry"*:

1. If you just want to set the entry text to be empty:

   ```
   $com_entry->child->set_text ("");
   ```
2. If you want to select nothing:

   ```
   $com_entry->set_active (-1);
   ```
3. If you want to remove a selected item from the popup menu:

   ```
   my $model = $com_entry->get_model;
   my $iter = $com_entry->get_active_iter;
   defined $iter and $model->remove ( $iter );
   ```

Hope it is helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of guessing here, I use GTK+ in my MonoDevelop projects, and I toy around with PERL when I need something quick and dirty. What about something like: `$com_entry->append_text("");`?

You might get some other ideas from: [here:](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcomboboxentry.html)

Comment: Did you check the link for ideas? I got the impression that GTK2 PERL documentation is a little thin on the ground, maybe look into GTK2 documentation and give it the mental spin so that it works in PERL.

Comment: Yes, I did. I read some other sites and doc for Gtk2::ComboBoxEntry but there are only methods which just insert or append text into a ComboBox's list of values. But for me is needed to clear what user typed in Entry field of ComboBoxEntry.

Comment: Oh, ok, I've just edited your post to make it more clear. Maybe someone will be able to answer what you really want.

Comment: What about: gtk.ComboBox.remove_text()? Which would be: $com_entry->remove_text(); ?

Comment: $combo_box->remove_text ($position)
       ·   $position (integer)
This method need to get a position number of text for remove but text entered by user into Entry field doesn't have a position number!

Comment: One might expect that it would be either "0", or "1" after the user enters something. It would not be "VOID".

Comment: Unfortunately the indexes is begun from 0 to N. 0 means the first value in a model ComboBoxEntry. So it doesn't work too.

Comment: Well, if there is a method to tell you the number of entries, let's call it "N", then simply delete the "N-1"th entry. DONE

Comment: Well, I didn't notice any methods, or properties which will help you know how many entries have been made in the comboBoxEntry, so if you make a variable to keep track of that then you can do what I mentioned in my comment above. I know it looks kinda kludgy but I don't see an easier way to do it in GTK2. CHEERS